# How to Control Table Cell Width When Inserting INPUT Field with JQuery

Tags: jquery, css, html-table, air, webkit

I've got an edit in place feature on a web page that is targeted for webkit.
The HTML is trivial.

I attach a click handler to each cell with jQuery:

```
$("table td").click(editMe);

function editMe(e) {
  var w = $(this).width();  // returns cell width
  $(this).html("<span>Foo</span");  // does not change table width
  $(this).html('<input type="text" />');  // CAUSES CELL width to BLOW UP! (gets VERY wide)

  var in = $('<input type="text" />');
  in.width(w-10);
  $(this).html(in);    // CAUSES CELL WIDTH TO BLOW UP!  (nearly doubles)
}
```

No amount of setting the width seems to make ANY difference.  Input has no padding, or margins, no borders.  The table cell width just goes berzerk.  Focus is on Webkit (Safari / Adobe AIR).  But WHY?

How can I have the input dimensions MATCH the table cell it is being inserted into?

Comment: First off, attaching the click to every td is a bad idea.  Attach a handler to the table via delegate.  Second, if you put together a jsfiddle.net I'd be a lot more willing to help.

Answer (score 0):

Okay,
I didn't get the exact answer, but it turns out the culprit lay in the reset.css file of the 960Grid CSS Framework.  I don't know exactly which setting caused the bizarre behavior, but removing that file fixed it.

960Grid is a simple CSS Framework I like to work with but something about their reset.css file caused my tables to blow up.  As soon as I removed that file, the tables behaved as expected.